# Brackets font weight is bold?

Tags: adobe-brackets

How do I change Brackets' font weight? [Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7i19f.png) to see how it's on fresh install with `Brackets Dark`.

Comment: Change font weight to what? Already looks bold to me!

Comment: I want to look normal, it's very bold, and I didn't do anything. Can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Never done it before but take a look at this reference: http://worldofgnome.org/change-fonts-on-brackets-writing-brackets-extensions-example/ Looks like you need to build your own extension. Doesn't look too scary :)

Answer (score 0):

The font weight is controlled by the theme you select. Use the Extension Manager (that thing that looks like a lego brick in the right column), go to the Themes tab and install a theme like solarized-light. Then back in Brackets use the View menu and select that theme.

Of course I would be remiss if I didn't mention the Delkos Dark Theme, which is worth looking at just for the way it does bracket matching.